# How to zip and fetch a file remotely

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

My company has a machine in a remote location. The application we use creates log files in a /log folder on disk. We have a vpn connection to the machine, however it is quite slow. 
Now and then I need, or get asked to download the log files from the machine. 
To increase speed, I'd like to zip the files before sending.

Right now i have to do this Via vnc, using 'send to' -> .zip. I can then use windows explorer to copy the file and paste it in a local folder.

Can i however use windows explorer to zip the file without me having to go through VNC to zip the file? If i use the same step as above to zip  the file, it seems like windows will download the files locally, then zip them and then place them back in a .zip on the remote machine. This is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows PowerShell 5.0 installed on the remote host.

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName RemoteServerName` will be open remote session

`Compress-Archive -Path C:\logfile.log -Destinationpath C:\logfile.zip -CompressionLevel Optimal`

`Exit` will be closed remote session

`Copy-Item -Path \\RemoteServerName\C$\logfile.zip -Destination C:\logfile.zip`

Comment: That is one way for sure. However I googled for a small bit and i cannot easily copy over files from remote to local via powershell, meaning i would still have to run the command, then go back to explorer. This would not be that much faster than using vnc to zip and the explorer to download the file.

Thanks for your contribution btw!